# uninstalling a package

Tags: software-installation, python

It's true that I'm very new to ubuntu, and that I like to try stuff. Last thing that I've tried and didn't work as expected, was to install [mnemosyne](http://mnemosyne-proj.org/download-mnemosyne.php) app.

I followed the readme, but idk why I chosen to copy the mnemosyne folder content to `/opt/mnemosyne` and to run the `sudo python setup.py install` from there.

On the `mnemosyne` I get the message from the image below. After that I've run the `python setup.py install` from the `Downloads/mnemosyne-2.3.1`.

At this point, idk where I've made first mistake or how to fix it. Can I have your feedback?

Many thanks in advance!!!

[image: error message after running mnemosyne command]

Comment: Now what's your question? Uninstalling the program again or fixing the error?

Comment: I'd try to install Mnemosyne from the Ubuntu Software center - this is a slightly older version, but also installs sqlLight which apparently you need.  If that works, you could then retry installing the version that you downloaded from Mnemosyne.

Comment: @the_Seppi: I'll need to install and install it properly. Basically I'll need to understand the process. Please make ur comment as an answer, so I can vote for it

Comment: @CharlesGreen: it works. TY. please make ur comment as answer, in order to vote for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message indicates that you are missing a couple of required components.  One way to fix this would be to install Mnemosyne from the Ubuntu Software center, which will also install the required components.  Then you can try to use the tarball to update the software to the current version.